# why concat function is not working in php code for executing mysql query?

Tags: php

I'm getting error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback_test\tab.php on line 16

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

 $dep=4;   

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());


$stmt = 'SELECT ( CONCAT(getSem(sb.semid), ' (', getBranch(sb.bid), ') ') ) AS branch, 
           fc.sname, 
           sb.sub_full_name       AS SUBJECT, 
           FORMAT(Avg(fb.avg), 2) AS AVG 
    FROM   faculty fc, 
           subject sb, 
           feedback fb, 
           branch br 
    WHERE  fc.fid = sb.facultyid 
       AND fc.fid = fb.fact_id 
       AND fb.subid = sb.subid 
       AND fc.fid = fb.fact_id 
       AND br.bid = fc.bid 
       AND br.bid = 4 
    GROUP  BY fc.fid, 
              subject ';

$result = $conn-> query($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need '(' before CONCAT

It should be `SELECT CONCAT(...)` and also dont forget do delete closing ) before `AS BRANCH`

Comment: Thanks dude!.I tried by adding back slash to the concatination function(to add braces) it worked now.  "CONCAT(getSem(sb.semid),\' \(\', getBranch(sb.bid),\'\) \') AS branch"

Comment: I am glad it worked. Accept the answer so others can get help as well :)

Comment: I also added your said changes which worked proper.